# What methods exist to auto-generate ruby client stubs from WSDL files?

Tags: ruby, soap

I'm using Ruby and the Savon gem to interact with SOAP/WS and would like to auto-generate the client request methods from the WSDL in Ruby.

Before I do this, I'd like to know if there's any other Ruby/SOAP library that does this?

*Edit: Please note, I already know this isn't available in Savon out the box, in fact my intention is to add in the feature, I'm in the process checking if this exists somewhere else written in Ruby.*

Answer (score 2):

Since it's only few days since you asked this question, and I've run into same problem I've decided to create small script to do that.

Download - save as *objects.rb* for example and run with _bunde exec objects.rb path_to.wsdl_

https://gist.github.com/4622792

Let me know if it works ^^

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll give it a try later today.

Comment: I did not, our client switched services away from soap

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Savon's spec](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/tree/master/spec), it has pretty rich testing environment

Comment: I've already spoken to the author, it doesn't currently do this, I was going to add in the feature, I want to make sure I'm not duplicating work first.

Answer (score 0):

I think `ads_common` by Google is relevant to you.

[google-api-ads-ruby/ads_common at master · googleads/google-api-ads-ruby](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/tree/master/ads_common)

`rake generate` can create the client libraries automatically from WSDL.

It is specialized for Google Ads, but this notion would be helpful to create a versatile client library automatically from WSDL in Ruby.